# MongoDB group close values together

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping

I want to group close values together in my aggregation pipeline. Something like: if the distance I want is 2, then I will go over each element in the array and if the distance between the current element and the previous element is less than 2, group them.

Example:

the array is `[1, 2, 4, 7, 8]` and the distance I want is **2**.

First, check if `2 - 1` is less than or equal to **2** which it is so they are grouped together. The current group is `[1, 2]`

Then check if `4 - 2`  is less than or equal to **2** which it is so 4 is also added to the group. The current group is `[1, 2, 4]`

Then check if `7 - 4` is less than or equal to **2** which it isn't so the last group stays as `[1, 2, 4]` and now in the current group, it is only `[7]`.

Then check if `8 - 7` is less than or equal to **2** which it is so the first group is still `[1, 2, 4]` and the current group is `[7, 8]`.

I don't know if this is clear enough, please ask for details if you feel like it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First challenge is to define the groups. One solution is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         a: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$a",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                     "$$value",
                     [{
                        val: "$$this",
                        group: {
                           $cond: {
                              if: { $lte: [{ $subtract: ["$$this", { $last: "$$value.val" }] }, 2] },
                              then: { $ifNull: [{ $last: "$$value.group" }, 0] },
                              else: { $add: [{ $last: "$$value.group" }, 1] }
                           }
                        }
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
])
```

returns

```
"a" : [ 
    { "val" : 1, "group" : 0 }, 
    { "val" : 2, "group" : 0 }, 
    { "val" : 4, "group" : 0 }, 
    { "val" : 7, "group" : 1 }, 
    { "val" : 8, "group" : 1 } 
]
```

And then you need some cosmetic to bring it into final structure:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         a: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$a",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                     "$$value",
                     [{
                        val: "$$this",
                        group: {
                           $cond: {
                              if: { $lte: [{ $subtract: ["$$this", { $last: "$$value.val" }] }, 2] },
                              then: { $ifNull: [{ $last: "$$value.group" }, 0] },
                              else: { $add: [{ $last: "$$value.group" }, 1] }
                           }
                        }
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$a" },
   { $group: { _id: "$a.group", data: { $push: "$a.val" } } },
   { $group: { _id: null, a: { $push: "$data" } } }
])

{
   "_id": null,
   "a": [
      [1.0, 2.0, 4.0],
      [7.0, 8.0]
   ]
}
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HR2SMxP7Uxd)